# How to solve this homogenious first-order differential equation in python? x*∂y/∂x=y+2x^3*sin^2(y/x)

Tags: python, sympy

x*∂y/∂x=y+2x^3*sin^2(y/x)

This is what I tried:

```
from math import *
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x')
y = symbols('y', cls=Function)

eq = Eq(Derivative(y(x),x), 2*x**2 * sin(y(x)/x)**(2) + y(x)/x)
display(eq)

an_sol = dsolve(eq, y(x))
display(an_sol)
```

But it shows problem:

```
NotImplementedError: The given ODE -2*x**2*sin(y(x)/x)**2 + Derivative(y(x), x) - y(x)/x cannot be solved by the lie group method
```

Comment: Apparently, Sympy is not powerful enough to solve this equation. You should try Mathematica [`y(x) = -x arcctg(x^2 - 2 C1)`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DSolve%5Bx+y%27%5Bx%5D+%3D%3D+y%5Bx%5D+%2B+2+x%5E3*Sin%5By%5Bx%5D%2Fx%5D%5E2%2C+y%5Bx%5D%2C+x%5D)

Comment: I was just about to say you can get that by hand too...

Comment: My assignment requires me to solve it both manually and in python. I did it by hand, but I am struggling with coding (I started learning it just 2 weeks ago). I have tried Mathematica, but it gave an error: can't convert expression to float

Comment: If this is for a class, you should be able to solve with the code that's been introduced in the class already.  Otherwise it's a poorly designed class.

Comment: non linear ode's (even first order) are very hard to solve analytically. most can't be solved except numerically. But this one seems that sympy should have been able to solve it. If assignment requires you to solve it in sympy, and sympy can't solve, then what does the teacher expect you to do in this case? Write a dsolver in python from scratch?

Comment: Maybe the assignment expects to use Python for a numerical solution.